# MySQL count on Grouping

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to count the number of times a grouping occurs in a query.

```
SELECT COL1, 
       COL2, 
       *(count COL1)* 
  FROM TABLE 
 GROUP BY COL1, COL2
```

So I'm expecting to see the results like so:

```
COL1, COL2, Count

A,    A,    1
A,    B,    2
B,    A,    1
B,    B,    2
B,    C,    3
```

`Count(*)` will give me the sum of the grouped row which is what I don't want, but I just cant seem to get my head round it or find a way to do it. Anyway, thanks in advance.

Comment: This maybe what you are looking for http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx

Comment: do you have any primary keys in your table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `auto_increment` column to make an order. After that, try something like this:

```
 SELECT a.col1, a.col2,
                  (SELECT Count(*) From T1 c 
                   WHERE c.col1 = a.col1 
                   AND c.ID <= a.ID) as count
 FROM T1 a;
```

**[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b93690/2/0)**

OR Without `auto_increment` Try this:

```
SELECT col1, col2,
   (select count(*) from T1 t2
    where t2.col2 <= t1.col2 and
          t2.col1 = t1.col1 
   ) as Enumeration
FROM T1 t1
GROUP BY col1, col2;
```

**[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aef32/4/0)**

Comment: I like that but unfortunately adding any other fields including auto_increment is not an option.

Comment: @JoeMalloy you welcome, just mark it as an answer if it siuted you.

Answer (score 1):

Your query (with the parentheses appropriately placed) does what you want:

```
SELECT COL1, COL2, count(*)
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY COL1, COL2;
```

If you want the *sum* of a column, then use the `sum()` function.

EDIT:

If you are trying to *enumerate* the groups (despite what the question is asking in rather clear English), you can do:

```
SELECT col1, col2,
       (select count(*)
        from table t2
        where t2.col1 = t.col1 and
              t2.col2 <= t.col2
       ) as Enumeration
FROM table t1
GROUP BY col1, col2;
```

Comment: It wont produce desired output.

Comment: No it doesn't, I require a count on each grouped COL1